# cannot clear Interval within if query

Tags: javascript

I am learning about the setInterval and clearInterval method and meanwhile there appeared some problems with my learning process. In the code below you can see the function countdown which is including the var y which should be increased after every 500 milliseconds. If the var y reaches the value 3 the Interval should be cleared. But my code is not working like I actually want. What I am doing wrong?

```
  let y = 1
function countdown() {
    
    y += 0.5
    console.log(y)
}

const timerId = setInterval(countdown, 500)

if( y > 3) {
    clearInterval(timerId);
}
```

Comment: Your pretty close. Just need to put the `( y > 3)` within the `countdown` function. Currently it'll only be executed once, and at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the `( y > 3)` check within the `countdown` function. Currently it'll only be executed once, and at the end.

Here's a working example:

```js
let y = 1;

const countdown = () => {
  y += 0.5;
  console.log(y);
  if( y >= 3) {
    clearInterval(timerId);
  }
}

const timerId = setInterval(countdown, 500);
```

Comment: Thank you firstly. But I intentionally avoided this way because I want to have access of clearInterval with an own function. When I for example would press a stop button then I would want to have connect the clearInterval with this button or function respectively. I could not implement this when I wrap clearInterval in the countdown function, right?

Comment: Then just extract `clearInterval` to it's own function, so you can call it from either within your function, or externally. But this requirement was not mentioned in your question.